# 1-bit based Bitmap in Android

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-canvas

I am trying to cache big bitmaps for drawing on screen in Android. But now I am facing OutOfMemoryException, say that the bitmap allocation exceeds the VM budget.

I need to minimize the size of the bitmap but I cannot reduce the resolution. For my use case, I need to only save the shape of the bitmap and apply color later when actually drawing, so I am using ALPHA_8 as the bitmap configuration.

I want to know if there is a 1-bit pixel (either completely opaque or completely transparent) configuration in bitmap, or any similar ways to save memory?

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the color depth from 8 bits to 1 would, of course, help a little. However, it doesn't really solve the problem but just postpones it. It only means that you'll get the OOME *later* but you'll still get it.

Consider moving your cache from RAM to disk and, optionally, add a smaller RAM-based cache on top of it to improve performance.

Comment: Most situations, your way is the best for solving OOME. But in fact my bitmaps are a cache of a canvas drawn from large number of shapes. I store a cache to improve the responsiveness to my app, so rather than storing to hard disk, I would rather draw them again. I was just wondering if 1-bit is possible as this would allow me to store more cache with the same memory space.